# How to debug ingress-nginx-controller for lost response time?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I have a weird issue with my ingress-nginx-controller.
Sometimes there are following log values from the ingress-nginx-controller

```
upstream_duration: 4.560s, 0.328s
```

Where did 4 seconds go?

Upstream is another nginx with a duration of 0.328s

Did anybody experience something like this before?
How could I debug this?